# How do I pass an interface as a parameter to a method?

Tags: c#

I am a  newbie to C#. Could you please tell me how to pass an interface as a parameter to a method?
i.e. I want to access the interface members(property) and assign the values to it and send that interface as a parameter to another method.

Say for example if I have an interface as **IApple** which has members as property **int i** and **int j**
I want to assign values to **i** and **j** and send the whole interface as a parameter say like this

**Method(IApple var);**

Is it possible? Sorry if am poor at basics please help me out. thanks in advance

Comment: It's too trivial. Just try searching. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0140__Class/Useinterfaceasaparameter.htm

Answer (score 43):

Sure this is possible

```
public interface IApple
{
    int I {get;set;}
    int J {get;set;}
}

public class GrannySmith :IApple
{
     public int I {get;set;}
     public int J {get;set;}

}

//then a method

public void DoSomething(IApple apple)
{
    int i = apple.I;
    //etc...
}

//and an example usage
IApple apple = new GrannySmith();
DoSomething(apple);
```

Comment: @ jack: in other words you must implement a class that implements that interface (GrannySmith), create an object of that class and hand that over to the method : **DoDomething(new GrannySmith());**

Comment: yup thanks... but i am getting null exception was not handled during run time at that method wen iam trying to pass this interface... what may be the problem?

Answer (score 16):

Say you have the following classes:

```
public interface IApple{
    int I {get; set;}
    int J {get; set;}
}

public class GrannySmith : IApple{

    public GrannySmith()
    {
        this.I = 10;
        this.J = 6;
    }
    int I {get; set;}
    int J {get; set;}
}

public class PinkLady : IApple{

    public PinkLady()
    {
        this.I = 42;
        this.J = 1;
    }
    int I {get; set;}
    int J {get; set;}
}

public class FruitUtils{
    public int CalculateAppleness(IApple apple)
    {
         return apple.J * apple.I;
    }
}
```

now somewhere in your program you could write:

```
var apple = new GrannySmith();
var result = new FruitUtils().CalculateAppleness(apple);
var apple2 = new PinkLady();
var result2 = new FruitUtils().CalculateAppleness(apple2);

Console.WriteLine(result); //Produces 60
Console.WriteLine(result2); //Produces 42
```

Comment: why not make CalculateAppleness as extension method :-)

Comment: Would it be wrong to use public int CalculateAppleness(GrannySmith gs)? What is a conceptual difference?

Comment: @mko I have added another apple to clarify. If we made `CalculateAppleness` take an instance of `GrannySmith` instead of an `IApple` we would no longer be able to calculate the appleness of a pink lady apple. See the difference?