# Pass an interface as a parameter instead of a specific type

Tags: c#, .net

Assume we have this

```
    class A { }
    class B : A, IB { }
    interface IB { }
    class C
    {
        private readonly _ib;
        public C(IB ib) {_ib = ib;}
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            SomeOtherMethod(ib) //which actually requires an object of type A.
        }
    }
```

`SomeOtherMethod` requires an argument of type `A`, but I am trying to call it with `IB`, but it does not work, it says:

> Cannot convert from IB to A

Why is that? What to do to overcome this?

Comment: You have not implemented IB for the class A. Implement it and it will not give you that error, also change the input parameter to IB from type A

Comment: What is `SomeOtherMethod` signature, please?

Comment: `private readonly _ib;` isn't valid C# code. Please provide the full code.

Comment: I mean the error message tells you all you need to know, no, You cannot convert `IB` to `A`, they have no relation. I'm not sure what part of this you don't understand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass an interface as a parameter to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748330/how-do-i-pass-an-interface-as-a-parameter-to-a-method)

Comment: I guess you need to understand that there is no relation between `IB` and `A` at all. There is a relation between `B` and `A` and `B` and `IB` but that does not mean that `A` inherits from `IB`

Answer (score 0):

An interface is less specific than a class.  You can't pass in an interface to satisfy a class parameter.

You can convert from the interface to the class if you have such a conversion defined, but it's a narrowing conversion, so C# won't do it automatically (unless you were to define it as an implicit conversion).

Comment: While this answer is correct, based on the question I'm not sure it's usable to the OP. Seems to me like the OP has a too big gap in understanding of how c# interfaces and classes work to understand this answer - but of course, I might be wrong.

Comment: @ZoharPeled You're certainly welcome to supply a better answer, or to edit this one to improve it.

Comment: I'll pass, thanks. I don't think I can provide a really good answer to this question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the keyword [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) to check if some types (in example an interface against a class) are compatible, and then [as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) to convert the object to the desired type.

`IB` is not necessary `A` because `IB` can be implemented by other classes that don't inherit from `A`

```
class D : IB { } //(d is A) == false
```

In example, using your class structure :

```
class A { }
class B : A, IB { }
interface IB { }
class C
{
    private readonly IB _ib;
    public C(IB ib) { _ib = ib; }

    public void SomeOtherMethod(A a)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I am A");
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        if (_ib is A)
            SomeOtherMethod(_ib as A); //which actually requires an object of type A.
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("I am not A");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C(b);
        c.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

**Output**

> I am A

Comment: Probably because you're not answering the question at all. Also, almost every time you think you need to write `x is y` in code is probably a code smell and an anti-pattern. And this answer is not a good way to do it.

Comment: @DavidG would you explain a bit more why `x is y` is bad?

Comment: Because it's almost always a sign that you're doing something wrong. For a start it's violating SOLID.

Comment: @DavidG I'm curious about what would be your approach, in another context (with concrete example) to avoid using `is` / `as`. Let's discuss about it in a chat ?

Comment: The real and robust solution is to fix the code so the type check isn't needed. For example, passing round an interface rather than a concrete type. `SomeOtherMethod` shouldn't take an `A` to start with.